# KeyError but Dict is valid and contains the correct key

Tags: python, flask

I'm running a small Flask application that talks with Elasticsearch and presents some formatted stats from the data it gets back from ES.

I have a particular query that returns a dict of values.

Returned data from the query :

```py
{'took': 6, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 72, 'successful': 72, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 84, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}, 'aggregations': {'all_matching_docs': {'buckets': {'all': {'doc_count': 84, 'total_traffic': {'value': 10276020.0}, 'host_traffic_rate_bit_s': {'value': 0.27402719999999997}}}}}}
```

From a standalone Python script, I'm using the following data structure to access the value of "host_traffic_rate_bit_s".

```py
test = res_bucket_test['aggregations']['all_matching_docs']['buckets']['all']['host_traffic_rate_bit_s']['value']
print(test)
0.27402719999999997
```

It works and shows the correct value.

I am using the exact same logic in the Flask App but I have to wrap the same structure in a try/except. If I don't, I get the following error

```py
total_mbit_s = res_mbit_s['aggregations']['all_matching_docs']['buckets']['all']['host_traffic_rate_bit_s']['value']
KeyError: 'host_traffic_rate_bit_s'
```

With the try/except structure.

```py
try:
  total_mbit_s = res_mbit_s['aggregations']['all_matching_docs']['buckets']['all']['host_traffic_rate_bit_s']['value']
except:
  total_mbit_s = 'potato'
```

Note that the 'potato' value is never assigned to the variable. The end result is still the value contained inside the `value` variable.

I get the right value displayed by Flask.

I know that the data is correctly parsed and sent to Flask as if I just display `res_mbit_s['aggregations']['all_matching_docs']['buckets']['all']`, I get `{'doc_count': 121, 'total_traffic': {'value': 147044.0}, 'host_traffic_rate_bit_s': {'value': 0.003921173333333333}}` which means I should be able to access the "host_traffic_rate_bit_s" key for the Dict.

I'm not sure where the code could fail. The only "real" difference is running the .py standalone or within the Flask app itself when the URL is called.

Let me know if you need more details!

Comment: can you show a minimized/simplified version of the flask app, please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

So I started from scratch and realized that a key difference was the source of the request. I am using the source IP to find the relevant traffic from ES and it seems that the key is not be returned if the source IP does not have any traffic logged in ES.

1. If the request came from an IP known to ES = data is returned and
   dict key is valid.
2. If the request is from an IP without any logs the dict is cut short and the value doesn't exist which is why the KeyError appers.

```py
try:
  total_mbit_s = res_mbit_s['aggregations']['all_matching_docs']['buckets']['all']['host_traffic_rate_bit_s']['value']
except KeyError:
  total_mbit_s = 0
```

Comment: A good tip is to use the `dict.get` method if you are unsure if a value exists and you want to supply a default value. e.g. `my_dict = {"foo": "bar"}; my_dict.get("eek", "abc")` in this case asking for the `eek` key will return the string `"abc"`.

Comment: That is more elegant than my try/except. I'll modify my side. Thanks!